# How to connect to a BGP network?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, datacenter, bgp

A service provider we're working with delivers us data via two(for resiliency) 1Gbps cross connects. He's located in a datacenter nearby the datacenter where our server is located. We *don't have* a switch, nor do we have a router, just one single Ubuntu server. Our server has a dedicated network card with two 1 Gb fiber ports that are meant to be used for the two cross connects.

Now, the service provider surprisingly asked for a AS number as well as "source network information". I just don't have enough network technology knowledge to figure out what I have to do. I've expected a TCP/IP connection.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible at all to connect to a BGP network without special
   hardware, just by configuring the Ubuntu OS accordingly?
2. What could be meant by "AS number" and "source network information"? Are there typical contents for a BGP network that I would have to deliver?
3. Which software could I use for the BGP setup on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: You should work with your DC to get this information.

Comment: @Hanginoninquietdesperation I've tried - they said it's not their business. And I gues they're right.

Comment: From your description, BGP is only relevant to your situation if that's the only way to connect to the service provider.  Your service provider should have a service definition which will define (hopefully several) acceptable ways to connect.  With luck, one of those will fit your situation.  Without any network knowledge though, you have no way to judge and I'd expect your SP to help you.

Comment: I haven't quite understaood how you access your server though if it's not attached to a network.

Comment: @marctxk The server is accessed via Internet. This works fine. The question is just about the connection to the SPs particular network.

Answer (score 4):

Answers:

1. Yes, it's possible to connect to a BGP network with Ubuntu server. You'll need to run a special software, have a network card with at least 2 interfaces, and of course to have connection to your BGP neighbor (the router of your provider, who will advertise your network to the Internet).
2. Please have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet). You can lookup AS Numbers at many places (https://www.ripe.net/manage-ips-and-asns/ipv4).
3. I've worked with http://www.nongnu.org/quagga/, it will do the job for you.